# Different types for Get(id) vs GetAll()

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am creating a very simple web api that allows me to search for things:

```
public IEnumerable<Thing> GetAllThings()
{
    // get all the things!
}
```

My application has to be able to retrieve a single Thing:

```
public Thing GetThing(string id)
{
    // get a single thing
}
```

I need more details when retrieving a single Thing than I do when I retrieve all Things. Should I have a separate controller  that returns a ThingWithDetails instead of having separate models on GetAllThings and GetThing?

Answer (score 0):

No. You do not have to make a separate controller for ThingsWithDetails. Just have a different overload method. All the below methods will be called based on the request

The below method will be called when you are using url: api/{controller}

```
public IEnumerable<Thing> GetAllThings()
{
    // get all the things!
}
```

The below method will be called when you are using url: api/{controller}/1

```
public Thing GetThing(string id)
{
    // get a single thing
}
```

The below method will be called when you are using url: api/{controller}?id=1&name=xyz

```
public Thing GetThing(string id, string name)
{
    // get a single thing
}
```

Comment: So are you proposing that Thing include the properties that I don't want included when returning a list of things and just leave them as their defaults?

Comment: Ideally, the coding practice says that the model for a particular controller should have all the possible properties that you need for that API. If you have totally different model that you want to return then better create a different controller for that.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you should have a `Thing` entity with all the possible properties, so you keep the code consistent, and by default you load all of them (assuming that they come from DB).

If you then want to "hide" some properties, you can set them to null just before returning them, using an extension method.

```
public class Thing
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
}

// extension methods
public static class ThingExtensionMethods
{
    public static void ToBasicDetails(this Thing thing)
    {
        // hide properties
        thing.PropertyB = null;
        thing.PropertyC = null;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<Thing> GetAllThings()
{
    var things = _db.Things.ToList();
    foreach(var item in things)
    {
        item.ToBasicDetails();
    }

    return things;
}

public Thing GetThing(string id)
{
    var thing = _db.Things.Find(id);
    return thing;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the details I do not want to load would put too much of a strain on the database to load in a list. They come from separate tables.

Comment: Then, either you can use Extension Methods in the same way and load the extra details when needed, or you can [eager-load](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx) them directly from the Controller when you need.

Comment: The problem with that approach is then the client gets a bunch of null fields in the response. You really want a DTO.

Comment: @MikeWasson you can configure json formatter (JSON.NET) to ignore the null properties

Answer (score 0):

Defining separate "Thing" and "ThingWithDetails" models makes sense, because you are returning different resource types to the client. The return type defines the response body, so use different models for different response formats.

You don't need to put those methods into separate controllers - it's valid to have an action that returns a ThingWithDetails and another action that returns IEnumerable. It comes down to preference. (I'd probably leave them in the same controller, because they are dealing with the same DB entity.)

[This](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) tutorial shows an example.